# Is the Token supposed to change each time?

Tags: python, json, django, jwt, postman

this is the tutorial i was following, the link

https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication

I was up to the end, the part that has this in bold
**"Retrieving and updating users with Postman"**

when i use Postman and do a POST Request on the url 127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/login
with the correct email and password, I get a different token each time I login, is this normal? if so how does the below work....

the problem is according to the tutorial when I do a GET on the url
127.0.0.1:8000/api/user

i get the response

{
  "user": {
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
  }
}

but according to the tutorial I should be getting the user's username . Am i sending the request wrong?

The comments in the code tell  me to use the token in the header of the request using PostMan, so i did this, and still same results. I even tried to put the token after user/?token='tokengoeshere', still same result.

The token changes each time i log in how will the token lead me to user.

The tutorial and the commented code in saying that if I use a token it is supposed to respond with a user and token.

Comment: Which framework are you using as your frontend? Token authentication are used for cross platform authentication purposes. If you are using django templating then session or basic authentication is enough.

Comment: the tutorial will use angular js for the front end, but i have not gotten to that point

Comment: Could you post the view?

Answer (score 0):

I have read the tutorial and as to my suspicion, your permission classes is (isAuthenticated, ).
It means you need to be logged in for making that request. That's why the error message.

By removing the permission classes attribute or changing it to (AllowAny, ), you can do the request without any problem. But retrieving a user logically requires authorization. That's why the permission classes.

Using tokens, in angular js, after posting to login API you would receive a token. Token would be different everytime. Tokens are meant to be some identity for a user used for Authorization. After logged in you should keep the token in your request header for every request until logout, then token is deleted. This token proves your authority in the server.

You need to keep reading the tutorial, and also write some interceptor service inorder to put the token in the request header everytime.

Try the get request by adding

'Authorization': your_token

in the header.
It should return response 200.

My advice is that, you skip the authentication part for now and focus on building a front-end and then come back after you have an idea how angularjs works and can be integrated to django.

Comment: thank you, i've figured out what was wrong, my secret key in my settings somehow was incomplete, i fixed it by copying there, going to take ur advice and do the front end so i can visually see everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , I did this:
[image: Enter Authorization Token *token in here*]